# How iteration ordering in LinkHashMap/LinkedHashSet leads to a bit low performance than HashMap

Tags: java, collections, linkedhashmap, linkedhashset

As LinkedHashMap/Set keeps the order of entry in the Collection so it leads to a little lower performance.
I want to know why this happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LinkedHash[Map/Set]` use doubly linked lists to keep track of the order of entries. So whenever an element is added, a new DLL node must be created. The allocation takes time, and several extra pointers need to be set.

Answer (score 1):

The question is making the invalid assumption that LinkedHash[Map/Set]s always perform worse than their non-linked counterparts.

The LinkedHash[Map/Set] has the additional task of maintaining the pointers used to form the linked list which means slightly worse (although still constant time) performance than Hash[Map/Set] when performing add or remove.

However, when iterating over a LinkedHash[Map/Set] the **performance is proportional** to the **size** of the set whereas the non-linked counterpart is proportional to the **capacity** of the set. When iterating over a Hash[Map/Set] the best case scenario is when the capacity is just big enough to fit all the elements (ie capacity=size) and in such a case it has the same performance. Also keep in mind that unless you have a very static set/map and you set the capacity it's unlikely that capacity will equal size.

So if you're more concerned with the performance of building your map/set then you should choose a HashMap or HashSet but if you're more concerned with iterating over that map/set choose a LinkedHashMap or LinkedHashSet.

See also: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedHashMap`/`Set` contains two data structures: hash table and linked list, so that insertion and deleting operations cause modification of two data structures, while the same operations on simple `HashMap` touch only one data structure (hash table). That is why `LinkedHashMap`/`Set` is slower and consume more memory.